# Join table with multiple rows to one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a database that looks like:

```
TABLE 1
ID | NAME | PRICE

TABLE 2
TABLE1.ID | ITEM
```

As you can see it is possible that table 2 can contain multiple references to table 1.

Is it possible to create a query that gives a result like this?

```
TABLE1.ID | NAME | PRICE | TABLE2.ITEM REC 1 |  TABLE2.ITEM REC 2 |  TABLE2.ITEM REC 3
```

Comment: There is nothing "normal" about MySQL.

Comment: MySQL-version 5.1.48. I hope you mean this?

Comment: Are you limited to mysql? Some small coding (for example php) would solve this problem easily, whilst even if possible, the solution with mysql will most likely take more time and effort.

Comment: No, I have the possibility to do everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider looking at this MySQL function: `GROUP_CONCAT(expr)`. It will sure answer your question

[Mysql Documentation - group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: It is not exactly what is needed, but pretty neat solution :) +1 from me

Comment: When I push this to a CSV-file the BLOB-value are integers, so this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT t1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.ITEM) AS Items
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.TABLE1_ID
GROUP BY t1.ID
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00862/1)